# Error in rosbag play despite setting use_sim_time param

Tags: kinect, rviz, rosbag, ros-hydro, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**(ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04)**

I am following the tutorial on [Recording and Playing Back Kinect Data](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback). First, I recorded a rosbag file using

```
rosbag record camera/depth_registered/image_raw camera/depth_registered/camera_info camera/rgb/image_raw camera/rgb/camera_info --limit=60 -O kinectbag
```

As suggested in the tutorial, before playing back, I need to set the `use_sim_time` parameter. To do this, first I launch openni_launch without loading drivers

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false
```

Then, I set the parameter with

```
rosparam set /use_sim_time true
```

and confirmed that the parameter has indeed been set with the `rosparam get /use_sim_time` command (which returns true).
I am trying to visualize the playback in rviz (added PointCloud2 to rviz with appropriate Fixed Frame and topic settings) using following playback command

```
rosbag play --clock --pause kinectbag.bag
```

At this point, the Status of PointCloud2 shows an error saying

> Transform [sender=/camera/camera_nodelet_manager]
> Message removed because it is too old (frame=[/camera_rgb_optical_frame], stamp=[1442173625.519280128])

and a warning is printed on the terminal (from which I invoked rviz)

> [ WARN] [1442177967.606387020, 1442173623.553857221]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.

I can see that prior to loading the `rosbag play` command, the ROS time in rviz is set to 0, and it changes to the timestamp of the first message in my rosbag recording after I issue the play command (hence, it is indeed using simulated time, and not wall time).

Can anyone point out what might be causing this error?

P.S: I know that hundreds of similar queries have been answered before here, but they all are resolved by setting the `use_sim_time` parameter. In my case, I am facing the issue in spite of doing that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217588/error-in-rosbag-play-despite-setting-use_sim_time-param/) by [shobhit6993](https://answers.ros.org/users/23863/shobhit6993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2015-09-13

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got it to work. I guess the issue was that I was setting the `use_sim_time` parameter **after** the launch command, because of which the nodes (already launched) did not get the information that they are supposed to use the simulated clock.

One thing I would like to point out is that the tutorial indeed indeed asks you to set `use_sim_time` before the roslaunch command. When I initially tried to do this, I got the following error

> ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

because, obviously, the master was not running. I feel quite dumb now, but this is kind of what happens when you blindly follow the sequence mentioned in the tutorial, and not use common sense. The tutorial skips the instruction to first run `roscore` (to get the Master running). The `roslaunch` command itself starts the Master, if one is not running; but without setting the `use_sim_time` parameter to true.

In case someone falls into this silly pit in future, the following are the correct sequence of commands to get around this issue:

`roscore`

`rosparam set /use_sim_time true`

`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false`

`rosrun rviz rviz` (to launch rviz for visualization, or any other method to see the messages being played back)

`rosbag play --clock --pause kinectbag.bag`

---

Originally posted by [shobhit6993](https://answers.ros.org/users/23863/shobhit6993/) with karma: 161 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-14**:
Thanks for the answer! Please consider updating the tutorial with these extra steps as well.

**Comment by [shobhit6993](https://answers.ros.org/users/23863/shobhit6993/) on 2015-09-15**:
Done. This marks my first contribution to any wiki :)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-15**:
Thanks for the contribution!